# Delete any lines starting with capital letter

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a large text file with thousands of words on each line.

How can I remove all lines starting with a capital letter and all lines that are just a single letter.

```
A          -> To be deleted
a          -> To be deleted
abjurer
abkar
abkari
Abkhas     -> To be deleted
Abkhasian  -> To be deleted
ablach
ablactate
ablactation
B          -> To be deleted
b          -> To be deleted
Bounce     -> To be deleted
...
...
```

Is it possible to do this with Bash.

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely possible using any of awk/grep/sed. Give it a go and let us know where you get stuck!

Comment: Do you want to delete lines that start with a single **letter** or single **character**? Edit your question to show what would happen to a line that just contains the number `3` for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is merely asking for code to be written without any attempt of solving the problem.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Apparently that doesn't matter, i raised a meta for this the other day, and they pretty much just said you can post anything you want and downvotes on it will prevent answers lol.

Comment: I approved the answer. @Johnsyweb, I dint ask for code to do this in python, java or Fortran,i explicitly requested for bash. That meant i had done a few attempts in bash. Thanks to all, anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -Ev '^([A-Z]|.$)' file 
abjurer
abkar
abkari
ablach
ablactate
ablactation
```

Or use sed to save changes also:

```
sed -i.bak -r '/^.$|[A-Z]/d' file
```

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

```
$ awk 'length($0)>1 && !/^[A-Z]/' file
abjurer
abkar
abkari
ablach
ablactate
ablactation
```

This checks that the string:

- Is more than 1 characters long.
- Does not start with any capital letter.

You can also follow [hek2mgl's good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100549/1983854) and use `!/^[[:upper:]]/'` instead of `!/^[A-Z]/` not to depend on your locale.

Comment: Can this be modified to capture lines with repetitive characters only?

`aaaa

aa

bb

bbbb`

Comment: This sounds quite different from the initial question and needs further information. You probably better ask a new question to make it clear.

Comment: That would remove blank lines and lines that contain a single character that is not a letter and in some locales will remove lines that do not start with upper-case letters.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '!/^([[:upper:]]|[[:alpha:]]$)/' file

grep -Ev '^([[:upper:]]|[[:alpha:]]$)' file

sed -r '/^([[:upper:]]|[[:alpha:]]$)/d' file
```

Comment: Why are you using `upper | alpha` ?

Comment: Note the `$` after `alpha`. It's `^upper` to delete lines that start with an upper case letter and `^alpha$` to delete lines that only contain a letter.

Comment: Oh yes, missed the position of the parentheses. Smart! :)

Answer (score 4):

I would use `sed` for this:

```
sed '/^.$/d;/^[[:upper:]]/d' file
```

This are two commands separated by a `;`. The first removes lines which contain of a single letter only, the second removes lines starting with a capital letter. I really encourage you to use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` to make it work independently from your locale.